# Shuffle an array of cards on click of a button

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, onclick

I want to be able to click on the button below and shuffle the cards in my card deck.
So far I have created an event listener which when clicked calls the function `shuffleCards` which takes an array. The array I have passed in is the one provided to me in the exercise which is an array of cards.

Nothing happens when I click on the button, I know it is something to do with scope but I do not know how to amend my code to make this work properly.

Thank you in advance.

HTML

```
<button type="button" id="shuffle" class="shuffle" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary">Shuffle</button>
```

JAVASCRIPT

// Part given in exercise which creates a deck of cards:

```
const suit = 'hearts';
const cardsWrapper = document.querySelector('.cards-wrapper');

function createCards() {
  const cards = [];
  // Create an array with objects containing the value and the suit of each card
  for (let i = 1; i <= 13; i += 1) {
    const cardObject = {
      value: i,
      suit,
    };
    cards.push(cardObject);
  }

  // For each dataObject, create a new card and append it to the DOM
  cards.forEach((card, i) => {
    const positionFromLeft = i * 15;
    const cardElement = document.createElement('div');
    cardElement.setAttribute('data-value', card.value);
    cardElement.classList.add('card', `${card.suit}-${card.value}`);
    cardElement.style.left = `${positionFromLeft}px`;
    cardsWrapper.append(cardElement);
  });
}
```

// part written by me

```
const shufflebtn = document.getElementById('shuffle');

shufflebtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  shuffleCards(cards);
})

function shuffleCards(array) {
  var i = 0
    , j = 0
    , temp = null

  for (i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i -= 1) {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1))
    temp = array[i]
    array[i] = array[j]
    array[j] = temp
  }
  return array
}
```

Comment: The `cards` variable is scoped to the function it's in. If you put the `const cards = [];` above that function. you should be able to access it in the event listener

Comment: Would be better to make it a return of `createCards()`;

Comment: I see you are returning cards back from `shuffleCards` function but you are not storing it in any variable, and also if you shuffled cards see logging it in console after shuffle function, if the cards really did get shuffled, updating the UI should be the next task I assume

Comment: @SriVenkataPavanKumarMHS Hello yes ok so I should store this function in a variable? Can you explain why? I am quite new to this. Also when i `console.log(array)` I can see that all it does is log 13 cards then duplicates them on the screen each time i click. Which means my shuffle is not working... Any pointers?

Comment: @AngelaInniss as I see your code to shuffle is working fine, to demonstrate it i have posted an answer, and referring to saving I asked to save the return value of the function into cards as I have shown in my answer, :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

made some changes to code where i am not talking about html instead giving a solution for your card shuffle. 
created a `create cards` button which triggers `createCards` function then, try clicking your shuffle and see console log you can see a shuffled array.
**Note: click on create cards Button before you click on shuffle as you might log empty array**
Also i changed the scope of cards as it should be accessible to other functions

```js
const suit = 'hearts';
var cards = [];

function createCards() {
  for (let i = 1; i <= 13; i += 1) {
    const cardObject = {
      value: i,
      suit,
    };
    cards.push(cardObject);
  }
}

const shufflebtn = document.getElementById('shuffle');
const creatorBtn = document.getElementById('creator');
shufflebtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
 cards = shuffleCards(cards);
})
creatorBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  createCards();
})

function shuffleCards(array) {
  var i = 0,
    j = 0,
    temp = null
  for (i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i -= 1) {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1))
    temp = array[i]
    array[i] = array[j]
    array[j] = temp
  }
  console.log(array)
return array;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="shuffle" class="shuffle" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary">Shuffle</button>

<button type="button" id="creator" class="creator" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary">create cards</button>
```

Comment: Hello @pavankumar This is really helpful and a lot clearer now.  I will take this and apply it to my code. THANK YOU!!